# What is the cleanest way to exit/kill/logout linux session?

Tags: linux, logout, xorg, xmonad, i3

I am using tiling window managers and from time to time I want to go back to a normal desktop environment or switch to another tiling window manager.

Usually I use a rofi script with `loginctl terminate-user $USER`.

Before this I used `pkill -9 -u $USER`.

I also found other options such as `loginctl kill-user $USER` and `pkill dwm` or `pkill i3`.

With so many options, I started to wonder which is the best and cleanest way to exit a session?

Answer (score 1):

To kill a window manager, you only need to kill the X server, leaving Linux and your login shell running.

For a general command, you can use:

```sh
 pkill -x X
```

In the specific case of i3, from [i3's documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_reloading_restarting_exiting):

> To exit i3 properly, you can use the exit command, however you don’t need to (simply killing your X session is fine as well).
>
> Example:
> bindsym $mod+Shift+e exit